# How do I count multiple duplicate elements in an ArrayList?

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, count, duplicates

I have a program that takes in a file list of bands and albums. I need to determine the number of album each band makes and then print out a list of the the bands and the number of albums they made in descending order. I have looked around and seen it done using mapping and collections. I want to know how to do it without either. Here is what I have so far:

```
public static void processFile(String filename)
{
    String bandname = "";
    String[][] data = read_spreadsheet(filename);
    //takes the file and converts it to a 2d array
    ArrayList<String> bands = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int rows = 0; rows < data.length; rows++)
    {
        bands.add(data[rows][0]);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<bands.size()-1;i++)
    {
        int albumcount = 0;
        for(int j = i+1; j<bands.size();j++)
        {
            if(bands.get(i).equals(bands.get(j)))
            {
                albumcount++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

input example:

```
band1 -album
band2 -album
band1 -album
band3 -album
band1 -album
band2 -album
```

output example:

```
band1: 3
band2: 2
band3: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Without collections? You want to use arrays?

```
String [] names = new String[data.length];
int [] counts = new int[data.length];

int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < data.lenght; i++ ) {
   while (j < data.length) {
      if (data[i][0].equals(names[j])) {
         found = true;
         counts[j]++;
         break;
      } else if (names[j] == null) {
         names[j] = data[i][0];
         counts[j]=1;
         break;
      }
      j++;
   }
}

// find max count
// println
// nullify element
// repeat

for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
    int max = -1;
    int k = i;
    int pos = -1;
    while ( k < j ) {
       if ( counts[k] > max ) {
          pos = k;
          max = counts[k];
       }
       k++;
    }
    if ( pos != -1 ) { // we found 
       System.out.println ( names[pos] + ": " + counts[pos]);
       counts[pos] = -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you sort the list of band names (with duplicates) and then count how many of each band name is in the list, you will get the album count for each band:

```
public static void processFile(String filename)
{
    //takes the file and converts it to a 2d array
    String[][] data = read_spreadsheet(filename);

    // get all the bands (with duplicates)
    ArrayList<String> bands = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int rows = 0; rows < data.length; rows++) {
        bands.add(data[rows][0]);
    }

    // sort the bands alphabetically
    Collections.sort(bands);

    int albumCount = 1;
    String currentBand = bands.remove(0);
    while(bands.size() > 0) {
        String nextBand = bands.remove(0);
        if(currentBand.equals(nextBand)) {
            albumCount++;
        } else {
            // print the current band album count and setup for the next band
            System.out.println(currentBand + ": " + albumCount);
            currentBand = nextBand;
            albumCount = 1;
        }
    };
    // print the final band album count
    System.out.println(currentBand + ": " + albumCount);
}
```

Comment: how can something like this be done without using Collection?

Comment: You could sort the array list manually, but why would you when Collections.sort() is available?

Comment: the issue is i only have
`import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.File;`
and I cannot import other utils